# how to insert the some columns from a sheet to another sheet some workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

i have an excel that containts 2 sheets and i need if in first sheet modify the number of column to automatically modify in sheet 2 the same.How can i do with an macro in vba excel? i've tried this code:

```
Sub sbInsertingColumns()
'Inserting a Column at Column B
Range("B1").EntireColumn.Insert
'Inserting 2 Columns from C

Range("C:D").EntireColumn.Insert
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to achieve. Maybe something like the following. Place code in your original sheet. An important caveat is that code cannot distinguish between column insert and column delete. Original idea from [Gary's Student](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/74f9e8e7-6e3a-4a32-a105-f505daccf6d8/ms-excel-worksheet-change-event-detect-insert-column-request?forum=isvvba).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Rows.Count = Rows.Count Then
        Worksheets("MyOtherSheet").Range(Target.Address).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End If
End Sub
```